# Very weird unhandled exception error at if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, bit-manipulation

So I have debugged my application and this is what the debugger told me:

[image]

At the line:

```
            if(p_IS_TRUE(playerid,CHECK_INACTIVITY))
```

Which is defined as:

```
#define p_IS_TRUE(playerid,check)      (p_CheckForStuff[playerid] & check)
```

So this is the important code:

```
//global
#define CHECK_SPAWNKILL         (128)   // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
#define CHECK_INACTIVITY        (256)   // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
#define CHECK_TELEPORT          (512)   // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000
#define CHECK_AIRBREAK          (1024)  // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000

unsigned long p_CheckForStuff[MAX_PLAYERS];
#define p_IS_TRUE(playerid,check)      (p_CheckForStuff[playerid] & check)
list<int> PlayerLoopList;

//When a player connects
    PlayerLoopList.push_back(playerid);
    p_CheckForStuff[playerid] =-1;//enable all checks

//When a player disconnects
    PlayerLoopList.remove(playerid);

//ProcessTick
    int playerid = 0;
    int ProcessTicksize = 0;
    int ProcessTickindex = 0;
    for (list <int>::iterator i = PlayerLoopList.begin(); i != PlayerLoopList.end(); ++i)
    {
        playerid = *i;
        int playerstate = GetPlayerState(playerid);
        int vid = GetPlayerVehicleID(playerid);
        if(g_IS_TRUE(CHECK_INACTIVITY))
        {
            if(p_IS_TRUE(playerid,CHECK_INACTIVITY))
            {
                if(p_AcivityInfo[playerid].Reported == false)
                {
```

and it can be reproduced as follow:

1) join the server
2) exit/ be kicked?
3) join again
4) crash

Does anyone know why this is happening? the code looks perfect to me..

Comment: You should try a debug build, and look at the values of the variables. In particular, is `playerid` a valid index for `p_CheckForStuff`?

Comment: Why do you have a vector for `PlayerLoopList` but not for `p_checkForStuff`? Are you sure `playerid` is always smaller then `MAX_PLAYERS`?

Comment: Does this happen at every iteration? Did you try manually specifying an int value for playerid in p_IS_TRUE?

Comment: well ok just wait for the results, i'll do a debug again

Comment: hmm the value of i is 4906632, is that the address ([ptr] 0x0212b958) or the value of playerid = *i; ?

 
weird value.

 
if it's *i

 
the debugger doesn't show anything for playerid, like it doesn't know what value it has

Comment: Are you running this in debug, not release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access Violations typically come from attempts to read through null pointers or uninitialized pointers or read off the end of an array.

In this case, you are reading an array value, so it would appear likely that the `playerid` value is greater than or equal to the `MAX_PLAYERS` bound of the array.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, now i need to find a fix heh. it's easy, but I think i;m going to switch to something other than list.